# Just want to export jquery in my bundle through webpack

Tags: npm, webpack, ecmascript-6, es6-module-loader

I am getting below error while building my module:

> Module parse failed:
>   D:\Projects\slacs-new\slacs-portal\portal-aggregator\js-module/src\index.js
>   Unexpected token (1:7) [INFO] You may need an appropriate loader to
>   handle this file type. [INFO] SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:7)
>   [INFO]     at Parser.pp$4.raise
>   (D:\Projects\slacs-new\slacs-portal\portal-aggregator\js-module\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2221:15)
>   [INFO]     at Parser.pp.unexpected
>   (D:\Projects\slacs-new\slacs-portal\portal-aggregator\js-module\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:603:10)

Webpack config content:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

var config = {
    context: __dirname + '/src', // `__dirname` is root of project and `src` is source
    entry: {
        app: './index.js',
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist', // `dist` is the destination
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/, // Check for all js files
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: { presets: ['es2015'] }
                }]
            }
        ]
    }
};


module.exports = config;
```

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "js-module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "babel-cli": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-core": "6.14.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^6.1.2",
    "babel-loader": "6.2.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.11.5",
    "babel-preset-decorators-legacy": "^1.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-preset-latest": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "eslint": "^3.9.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.6.0",
    "liferay-module-config-generator": "^1.1.10",
    "lr-js-core": "0.0.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2"
  },
  "scripts": {

    "bundle": "webpack --config webpack.config.js"
  }
}
```

My index.js

```
export $ from 'jquery';
```

As you can see, single line I've added and I am not able to figure out what else is required!

Please throw some light on this topic

Answer (score 0):

Correct export should be

```
export {default as $} from 'jquery';
```

or

```
import $ from 'jquery'

export { $ }
```

Or you need to include [transform-export-extensions](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-export-extensions/) plugin or use `stage-0` preset to make your syntax valid.